# Creating a complex data structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-modeling

I am trying to self learn c# (asp.net core) by creating a little quiz app, but I am confused on how to create a complex data model.
Imagine a quiz model with a collection of questions like this:

```
    public class Quiz
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public Icollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    }
```

But what if I want different kinds of quesitons (multiple choice, true/false, text answer...) Can I use inheritance to shorten somethings or do i just have to create a different model for each type of question and put them in like this:

```
Public class Quiz
{
   public Icollection<MultipleChoicQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
   public Icollection<TrueOrFalseQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
   public Icollection<TextQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: FYI, `public` is not capitalized and `ICollection` has a capital `C`...

Comment: The short answer is Yes, you can use inheritance and still have an `ICollection<Question>` (assuming the other types inherit from `Question`). The problem would come further down the line when you try to access child-class specific methods. Then you may end up with a bunch of `if (Questions[i] is TextQuestion)`. But if you can put all the public methods in the question class (actually it should be an interface), then it would work fine since each class handles it's implementation differently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please can you just put a little code down so I can get a better sense, I am new at this. If types of questions inherit from Question, then I don't have to put a collection of each type of question in the Quiz model? just a collection of question?

Comment: Correct. Try it and see what happens!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not totally related to .NET Core or EF, as you tagged, its about data modeling.

For those kinda different type Models, I suggest you make it as following.

Here is the `Quiz` Model.

```cs
public class Quiz
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Question with enum

```cs
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public QuestionType Type { get; set; }

    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public enum QuestionType
{
    MultipleChoice,
    TrueFalse,
    Text
}
```

And the last `Answers`

```cs
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int QuestionId { get; set; } 

    public Question Question { get; set; }

    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

For this way, the application layer will handle all process, but you'll store the data very easy.

For `MultipleChoice` questions, you add multiple answers and set `IsCorrect = true` which are correct.

For `TrueFalse`, add only 2 answer and set `IsCorrect = true` for the correct.

For `Text`, add only 1 answer and set `IsCorrect = true`.

Comment: Dude! This is awesome. One more thing, How about multiple people taking the Quiz? I would build another entity for each new student, right? Something Like "UserAnswers" with two foreign keys pointed at the Quiz Id and Question Id as well and a collection of all the student's answers for grading.

Comment: Exactly. You need one more object that  stores useranwers.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to create an `IQuestion` interface that contains all the public-facing methods and properties you need to run a quiz:

```
public interface IQuestion
{
    void AskQuestion();
    string CorrectAnswer { get; }
    bool IsCorrect { get; }
}
```

Then you can have a collection of this interface in your `Quiz` class:

```
public class Quiz
{
    public ICollection<IQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can create separate classes that each implement the `IQuestion` properties and methods in their own way.

For example:

```
public class TextQuestion : IQuestion
{
    public bool IsCorrect => string.Equals(_userAnswer?.Trim(), CorrectAnswer?.Trim(),
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public string CorrectAnswer { get; }

    private readonly string _question;
    private string _userAnswer;

    public TextQuestion(string question, string answer)
    {
        _question = question;
        CorrectAnswer = answer;
    }

    public void AskQuestion()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_question);
        _userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class MultipleChoiceQuestion : IQuestion
{
    public bool IsCorrect => _userIndex == _correctIndex + 1;

    public string CorrectAnswer => (_correctIndex + 1).ToString();

    private readonly string _question;
    private readonly List<string> _choices;
    private readonly int _correctIndex;
    private int _userIndex;

    public MultipleChoiceQuestion(string question, List<string> choices, int correctIndex)
    {
        _question = question;
        _choices = choices;
        _correctIndex = correctIndex;
    }

    public void AskQuestion()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_question);

        for (var i = 0; i < _choices.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}: {_choices[i]}");
        }

        _userIndex = GetIntFromUser($"Answer (1 - {_choices.Count}): ",
            i => i > 0 && i <= _choices.Count);
    }

    private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, Func<int, bool> validator = null)
    {
        int result;

        do
        {
            Console.Write(prompt);
        } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) &&
                 (validator == null || validator.Invoke(result)));

        return result;
    }
}

public class TrueOrFalseQuestion : IQuestion
{
    public bool IsCorrect => _userAnswer == _correctAnswer;

    public string CorrectAnswer => _correctAnswer.ToString();

    private readonly string _question;
    private readonly bool _correctAnswer;
    private bool _userAnswer;

    public TrueOrFalseQuestion(string question, bool correctAnswer)
    {
        _question = question;
        _correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    }

    public void AskQuestion()
    {
        _userAnswer = GetBoolFromUser(_question + " (true/false)");
    }

    private static bool GetBoolFromUser(string prompt)
    {
        bool result;

        do
        {
            Console.Write(prompt + ": ");
        } while (!bool.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result));

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
static void Main()
{
    var quiz = new Quiz
    {
        Questions = new List<IQuestion>
        {
            new MultipleChoiceQuestion("Which color is also a fruit?",
                new List<string> {"Orange", "Yellow", "Green"}, 0),
            new TextQuestion("What is the last name of our first president?", 
                "Washington"),
            new TrueOrFalseQuestion("The day after yesterday is tomorrow", false),
        }
    };

    foreach (var question in quiz.Questions)
    {
        question.AskQuestion();
        Console.WriteLine(question.IsCorrect
            ? "Correct!\n"
            : $"The correct answer is: {question.CorrectAnswer}\n");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Your final score is: " +
        $"{quiz.Questions.Count(q => q.IsCorrect)}/{quiz.Questions.Count}");

    GetKeyFromUser("\nPress any key to exit...");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you've helped very much. But just one question. That Quiz class with the IQuestion collection, i can't create an EfCore table with a collection of IQuestion collection, shouldn't I make a table for Question collection instead?